# How to query all history of specific user's activity?

Tags: openstreetmap, query, overpass-api

I would like to query all of the existing meta-data on a specific user using Overpass QL.  I am new to the format, but I know that this will return all the nodes in a box by a specific user:

```
node
    (uid:123456)
    (lat,long,lat,long);
out meta;
```

And I could run the same command for `rel`'s and `way`'s in order to get a complete data-set.  But this will not, as far as I can tell, show me the **history** of the user's activity, in that I won't be able to see the history of edits and changes, deleted items, etc.: only the stuff in the most recent changesets/versions.

I feel like there must be some command along these lines to accomplish what I want:

```
[diff:"YYYY-MM-DDTHH:MM:SSZ","YYYY-MM-DDTHH:MM:SSZ"];
(
  (uid:123456);
);
out body;
>;
out meta;
```

But as you can tell by running that [here](https://overpass-turbo.eu/#), it doesn't work.  Also, if it did work, it wouldn't really do what I want, since it would only tell me the difference between one date and the other, as opposed to a list of all the edits of any sort a person has done/made.  So the question is: **how can I query all of the meta-data on the activities of a specific user in Open Street Maps?**  (Doing so within a specific date-range and/or bounding box is a plus but not necessary, if your answer takes neither into account I can implement both features on my own after the fact).

EDIT -----
I was able to get results similar to what I'd like with this:

```
[out:csv(::type,::id,"name",::lat,::lon,::version,::timestamp,::changeset)]
[diff:"2012-08-14T15:00:00Z","2014-08-21T15:00:00Z"];
node
    (uid:1378531)
    (46.32701220,11.63249080,46.58063280,12.44677780)
out meta qt; 
rel
    (uid:1378531)
    (46.32701220,11.63249080,46.58063280,12.44677780)
out meta qt; 
way
    (uid:1378531)
    (46.32701220,11.63249080,46.58063280,12.44677780)
out meta qt;
 >; 
out meta qt;
```

But as of yet I am not totally sure if these results have **all** of the changes, or just the initial version and the latter version of any edited node.  **Moreover**, when I try running it with larger date ranges, the server gives me an empty package.  I am not sure how I'm supposed to query when I want something that necessitates more memory. Should I break it into multiple date ranges if the range is more than, say, a month, and then combine the results on my local machine after the fact? (It's not hard to combine CSV files with bash so this is definitely an option...)

Per a comment, I should mention that I do not have the flexibility to download gigabytes of data and parse through them.  I need to be able to download only the relevant data.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Overpass API doesn't support this requirement (yet), see https://github.com/drolbr/Overpass-API/issues/282 for the respective issue.

One option at this time is to process the Full History Planet using libosmium as an example, see http://planet.openstreetmap.org/pbf/full-history/ for the data and https://github.com/osmcode/libosmium for the library.

**Edit:** Depending on the kind of information you're looking for, http://hdyc.neis-one.org/ would also be worth looking at.

Comment: Thanks for responding!  The full history data is not a good option as it is a massive library and thus not useful for any sort of live applications where the end user expects to have results close to instantaneously.

Comment: You didn't mention this requirement in your question. Can you please edit your question to include _all_ of your requirements?

Comment: Please see my edit - I'd like to know if I solved it or not.

Comment: OK I will add the requirement to my question, but I think it's a fair one implicitly - the reality is that in almost all coding contexts you don't have 42 gb of space to just use, let alone the bandwidth to download all that.

Comment: Your query will only return differences between the first and the last timestamp, and _nothing_ inbetween => you won't get all of the changes that happen during that timeframe. Please refer to the Github ticket I mentioned. Also, you won't see any changes that happened before September 2012 (license change).
Empty result means, that there was probbaly a timeout issue. Unfortunately, you won't see error messages in CSV mode (that's another issue on Github). I would add something like `out count;` towards the end of the query to validate the response (see OSM wiki for details).

Comment: Very good point about cvs @mmd, thanks.  Do you know if I can just query for a node at a specific version or change-set?  I don't see any evidence online that I can but if it is possible that would fix the issues as the data I'm working with is rarely edited more than 3 or 4 times so I could just re-query.

Comment: Querying by version or changeset is also not available right now, but there are some enhancement requests on github for it already.